# How do I tell Vim to ignore certain "second extensions"?

Tags: vim

E.g. `foo.php.tpl` should be highlighted as PHP, `foo.js.erb` as Javascript, `foo.py.tmp` as Python...

Answer (score 2):

Try  `autocmd BufEnter` to set filetype. These are best added to `Vim/vimfiles/filetype.vim` inside the `augroup`

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.php.tpl set filetype=php
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.js.erb set filetype=javascript
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.py.tmp set filetype=python
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add something like this in `~/.vimrc`

```
au BufEnter,BufRead *.php.tpl set filetype=php
au BufEnter,BufRead *.js.erb set filetype=javascript
au BufEnter,BufRead *.py.tmp set filetype=python
```

Same as that of @leaf's answer but accounted for `BufRead` event also.